# How to send an embedded image without having an attached file?

Tags: phpmailer

When I send a photo, I receive it in the body of the email, but I also get an attached file with the path of this photo.

I also tried to send it as an attached file and not as an embedded image. I receive two files each time for a photo. One with the picture and the other with the path.

Here is my code:

```php
    for ($ct = 0; $ct < count($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name']); $ct++) {
        $uploadfile = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), hash('sha256', $_FILES['userfile']['name'][$ct]));
        $filename = $_FILES['userfile']['name'][$ct];
        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'][$ct], $uploadfile)) {
            $mail->AddEmbeddedImage($uploadfile, "my-attach" . $ct);
            // $mail->addAttachment($uploadfile, $filename);
        }
```

I would just like to get the photo without the file with the path name.

Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by "One with the picture and the other with the path"? Can you show the MIME structure of the received message?

Answer (score 0):

You can use base64 encoded image, and use html format for the email. Like this

```php
<img src="data:image/png;base64, <?=base64_encode($imageFileContent)?>" />
```